# Plotting 2D scatter plot from data in tsv file with ticks defined by user

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I want to plot a 2D scatter plot with the following details:

X axis ticks value as:

```
x = [0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,359]
```

Yaxis ticks value as:

```
y = [0,10,20,30,40]
```

Now, I have the following data in a tsv file which I want to plot with respect to X axis such that A,B,C,D columns have different color schemes.

```
A              B               C              D
0           
21.55741404    0        
41.2249925     52.96216168     0    
39.96376049    25.70840987     47.54439749    0
54.9600295     37.72928195     59.73455641    15.57652354
66.82671436    72.50071181     27.44853361    55.92679682
74.29259814    69.56620872     46.19494779    45.41791225

A values should lie where y = 10
B values should lie where y = 20
C values should lie where y = 30
D values should lie where y = 40
```

The output should be like the one as below:

[image: categorical plot]

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean `A values should lie where y = 10`? I'm unclear on where a standard plot is deficient and how the ticks should be applied. Can you share your current plot and how you'd like to modify it with the new ticks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need `sns.stripplot` and `melt`.

```
import seaborn as sns
dfm = df.melt()
sns.stripplot(dfm['variable'], dfm['value'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... I still don't understand the `x` and `y` tick values are considered.